# Making one command state dependent on other command toggle state in java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i'm trying to add dependency of one command active state with with other command toggling state and it does not work, the tester class is never called. what here is done wrong?

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
     <handler
        class="my.url.CaseSensitiveHandler"
        commandId="my.url.CaseSensitive">
        <enabledWhen>
          <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow">
          <instanceof value="org.eclipse.ui.services.IServiceLocator"/>
          <test args="my.url.ResultsRegex"
            forcePluginActivation="true"
            property="org.eclipse.core.commands.toggle"
            value="false"/>
          </with>
        </enabledWhen>
     </handler>
```

tester definition:

```
   <propertyTester
        class="my.url.CommandPropertyTester"
        id="my.url.commandPropertyTester"
        namespace="my.url"
        properties="toggle"
        type="org.eclipse.ui.services.IServiceLocator">
  </propertyTester>
```

I have tester class :

```
public class CommandPropertyTester extends PropertyTester {

@Override
public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
    if (receiver instanceof IServiceLocator && args.length == 1 && args[0] instanceof String) {
        final IServiceLocator locator = (IServiceLocator) receiver;
        if (TOGGLE_PROPERTY_NAME.equals(property)) {
            final String commandId = args[0].toString();
            final ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService)locator.getService(ICommandService.class);
            final Command command = commandService.getCommand(commandId);
            final State state = command.getState(RegistryToggleState.STATE_ID);
            if (state != null) {
              return state.getValue().equals(expectedValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and i have tested command handler defined like this:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    Command command = event.getCommand();
    //boolean oldValue =
    HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);

    final IWorkbenchWindow ww = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    final IEvaluationService service = (IEvaluationService) ww.getService(IEvaluationService.class);
    if (service != null)
      service.requestEvaluation("org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState");

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it was mistyped namespace in tester definition.